# Resampling data ending in specific data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, format, resampling

I have the following dataframe:
data

```
Out[8]: 
            Population
date                           
1980-11-03               1591.4
1980-11-10               1592.9
1980-11-17               1596.3
1980-11-24               1597.2
1980-12-01               1596.1
                        ...
2020-06-01              18152.1
2020-06-08              18248.6
2020-06-15              18328.9
2020-06-22              18429.1
2020-06-29              18424.4

[2070 rows x 1 columns]
```

If i resample it over a year i will get this:

```
data.resample('Y').mean()

date                           
1980-12-31          1596.144444
1981-12-31          1678.686538
1982-12-31          1829.826923
```

Is it possible for it to be resampled in way such that it is resampled ending on a specific date such as Jan 1st. Thus the dates would be `1980 - 1 -1` in the above example instead of `1980-12-31`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we can do is change to `YS`

```
df.resample('YS').mean()
```